# Function from a field that works half Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I notice something, the message is displayed as soon as I activate the boolean in Odoo. I would like the "half_pension is on" message to appear only when I save my form. How can I do that?

The save button is automatically included in Odoo

cordially –

My class :

```
class ResPartner_school(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.partner.school'
    _order = 'id desc'

    half_pension = fields.Boolean(string='Restauration Scolaire', copy=False)
```

My function :

```
@api.onchange('half_pension')
def synchroHalfPension(self):
    if self.half_pension:
        print "half_pension is on"
    else:
        print "half_pension is off"
```

Thanks you for help !

EDIT :

```
@api.multi
def changed_half_pension(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.half_pension:
            print "half_pension is on"
        else:
            print "half_pension is off"

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super('ecole.partner.school', self).create(vals)
    record.changed_half_pension()
    return record

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    result = super('ecole.partner.school', self).write(vals)
    self.changed_half_pension()
    return result
```

'ecole.partner.school' is my current class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the `print` statements will be in the end, to use the save button as call for changing something you have to override/extend `create()` and `write()` methods of your model.

```py
class ResPartner_school(models.Model):

    @api.multi
    def changed_half_pension(self)
        for record in self:
            if record.half_pension:
                print "half_pension is on"
            else:
                print "half_pension is off"

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = super(ResPartner_school, self).create(vals)
        record.changed_half_pension()
        return record

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        result = super(ResPartner_school, self).write(vals)
        self.changed_half_pension()
        return result
```

The `onchange` decorator is used to call the decorated method whenever the field is changed in the client. The change itself will be then saved by the button "save". So onchange behaviour is the wrong decision in this case.

Comment: I don't want to change the value of boolean. I just want see a print in terminal when i save and not when I click on the boolean ^^

Comment: I test your method. I have a problem when i save. Look : 
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not str

Thanks

Comment: And that problem is?

Comment: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not str

Comment: Show me your super call. You have to use your model classname as first argument.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect :) but why i should use the write method and the create method ? The create method not enough ?

Comment: The save button is calling both. When the record is not existing, Odoo will call create() and while editing an existing record Odoo will call write().

Comment: OK. Thanks you for help !